# In which MS Word version is the "Spike" included?

Tags: ms-word

I want to use the Spike in MS Word but I need to know which was the first version where it's integrated in Word. I couldn't find this information yet.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's integrated since Word 2013.

Comment: The Spike feature predates Word 2013. According to [Copying to the Spike](http://editorium.com/archive/copying-to-the-spike/), the Word Spike feature has existed at least as far back as Word 6, which [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Word#Word_1990_to_1995) was released in 1993.